# Viewing github project in python

Tags: python, github

I'm trying to view this project in python but there seems to be alot of extra characters.
https://github.com/riju18/East-West-University-library-management-system-python-desktop-Application/blob/master/python_distribution/app.py

Please can someone help me in viewing it in python without the extra characters?

Comment: What does "bite this project in python" mean?

Comment: At any rate, that's a Jupyter/IPython notebook, not a `.py` file. Rename it as `app.ipynb` and load it into Jupyter.